# getJSONObject returns wrong value

Tags: java, android

I`m consuming a REST Web Service that returns JSON. But the JSON Object value is

> "[12]"

when I println. The value must be only `12` without `"[]"`

Is my code wrong?
Theres my code:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://applocalize.com.br/rest/rest.php");

                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pg","categorias"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serv","buscar"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dt_atualizacao","0"));
                    try{
                        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){

                    }

                    HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
                    String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

                    if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                    {
                        System.out.println(respStr);
                        JSONArray temp1 = new JSONArray(respStr);
                        for (int i=0; i < temp1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = temp1.getJSONObject(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.getString("id"));
                        }


                    }
                    System.out.println("OKAY!");
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

There`s my logcat when I println the id

```
02-20 13:45:32.560  31135-31135/com.localizeapp I/System.out﹕ ["52"]
02-20 13:45:32.560  31135-31135/com.localizeapp I/System.out﹕ ["53"]
02-20 13:45:32.560  31135-31135/com.localizeapp I/System.out﹕ ["54"]
```

EDIT:

respStr:

02-20 13:45:32.210  31135-31135/com.allapps.localizeapp I/System.out﹕ [{"id":["51"],"titulo":["Chaveiro"],"icone":["a base 64 here....... too long"]

Comment: it's not parser's fault. Can you post the json?

Comment: What data getting in `System.out.println(respStr);` line?

Comment: i think you have a json array inside it.

Comment: Is simply doing a string replacement an option? can you post your json? has the json been validated? `obj.getString("id")[0]`?

Comment: `id`  is a `JSONArray`

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your web service is returning the values as `JSONArray`s. Either you can change the web service to send data as

```
"id":"51"
```

or you can replace

```
System.out.println(obj.getString("id"));
```

with

```
System.out.println(obj.getJSONArray("id").get(0));
```